# how to check "if image gallery is empty"

Tags: android

Im new to android and i need to know how to check the device image gallery is empty or not..

approach

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/images");
File dird = new File("/mnt/sdcard");

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
File[] filesd = dird.listFiles();

    if((files==null)||(filesd==null)){
    }
```

thanks

Comment: check with "files.length".If length>0 Sdcard contain images

Comment: the above approach is working properly for the emulator debugging. when USB debugging files.length always prompted null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null,null,null);
    int columnIndex = ursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    int size = cursor.getCount();
    // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
    if (size == 0) {

    } else {


    }
```

thanks all..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
private boolean isImageGalleryEmpty() {

        try {
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
            imagecursor.close();
            if (imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaSt... **managedQuery** got underlined in red.

Comment: put this function in your activity